# R how to output "\" in sprintf

Tags: r, printf

I want to `sprintf` a  string with a `"\"` in it but it doesn't work:

```
sprintf("& $\pm %s \delta$", 1.23)
Error: '\p' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""& $\p"
```

I have tried:

```
sprintf("& $\\pm %s \\delta$", 1.23)
[1] "& $\\pm 1.23 \\delta$"
```

But I need the result with `"& $\pm 1.23 \delta"`

How can I get the right result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're using it for but the `\\` will work if you're trying to use it in a .Rnw file for instance but R needs the `\\`.  If you just want to cut and paste it somewhere wrap it with `cat` as in: `cat(sprintf("& $\\pm %s \\delta$", 1.23))`

Comment: Is there no better way than cat(sprintf(...))? Double backslashes don't seem to work, as with this example: sprintf("test\\%s", "test"), nothing I do yields a single backslash save enclosing it in cat (which just seems hackish)

Answer (score 0):

The \ has an especial use. For example, \n is the new line character and will be printed as such and not as "\n".

If you want to print backslash, escape it with another backslash.  So "\" will print a single backslash.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

just write \\ - that will produce you a single slash. This is because a slash is a special character and it needs to be escaped before be printed ;)

Comment: even here in stack overflow the double slashes are some special combo, and to output a double slash you need to write triple slash.. huh